# Array results into Variable

Tags: php, arrays, date, post

I am trying to get a date which is entered into a table field (a future date so can't use standard variables), into the $date_tx variable.  The format of the field date is dd/mm/yyyy and for the database obvs needs to be yyyy-mm-dd.  The below kind of works, but the date_tx variable isn't getting fed with the result of the array...  What am I doing wrong?  I get the error: Notice: Undefined index: 2017-12-30 (which is the result of the array...).  I hope I'm making some sense, but please ask if not.

```
$theDate = $_POST['tx_date'];
$tempArray = explode("/", $theDate);
$date_tx = $_POST[$tempArray[2] ."-" .$tempArray[1] ."-" .$tempArray[0]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After retrieving the date from the `POST` data you no longer need to use `$_POST` to handle it as it is now stored in the variable `$theDate`. Simply removing `$_POST[...]` from the `$date_tx` variable assignment should fix your issue.

```
$theDate = $_POST['tx_date'];
$tempArray = explode("/", $theDate);
$date_tx = $tempArray[2]."-".$tempArray[1]."-".$tempArray[0];
```

When using it in `$_POST[...]`, PHP will look for a `key -> value` pair matching the input, in this case the date. Which is why the `undefined index` error was being displayed.

If you want to add your new value back to the `POST` data you can simply overwrite the existing value:

```
$_POST['tx_date'] = $date_tx;
```

You can also add it as a new value and completely skip the `$date_tx` variable:

```
$_POST['date_tx'] = $tempArray[2]."-".$tempArray[1]."-".$tempArray[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have something wrong in your typing .
it should be like this .

```
$date_tx = $tempArray[2] ."-" .$tempArray[1] ."-" .$tempArray[0];
```

and if you need to assign it to the `$_POST` `array` pass it as a variable with key and value pair ;

```
$_POST['newdate'] = $date_tx;
```

and as in your way . you can make it like this

```
$_POST['date_tx'] = $tempArray[2] ."-" .$tempArray[1] ."-" .$tempArray[0];
```